# Why is the bash caller built-in function returning a line number that is incorrect?

Tags: bash

I am iterating the caller stack to generate a return stack.  However, the top most frame has the correct function name and source file path that generated the error, but the line number is greater than the number of lines in the file.  Is this down to some sort of run-time parsing and line number skew?

```
function backtrace() {
    i=${1:-0}

    while caller $i >/dev/null ; do
        caller $i | while read ln fn src ; do
            printf >&2 "  File \"%s\", line %d, in %s\n" \
                "$src" "$ln" "$fn()"
        done
        (( i++ )) || true
    done
}
```

This function works everywhere perfectly except for this one case.  The file contains 107 lines, but the erroneous line number is being reported as line 128.

```
Traceback
  File "/home/phillipc/dev/extra/CI/jenkins/lib/soap.sh", line 128, in soap()
  File "./qasoap.sh", line 10, in request()
  File "./qasoap.sh", line 36, in _qa_soap()
  File "./qasoap.sh", line 147, in qa_soap()
  File "./qasoap.sh", line 164, in main()

ERROR: traps.sh: Unhandled error (exitcode: 8)
```

Comment: Please [post the relevant code.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See updated description with a shortened version of the backtrace function.  The backtrace function also outputs the erroneous line and contextual lines from the offending caller, but I have omitted this because it's irrelevant.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using a shorter soap.sh which you can post in its entirety?

Comment: How is `backtrace` function being called? via a `trap`, or some other mechanism?

Comment: Yes, it's called via an ERR trap (set -E).  Unfortunately, I can't post the contents of the soap script.  That said, it includes two other scripts (source notation) and defines a function called "soap" that implements a subshell `function() { ( stuff ... ; ) ; }`.  The script runs with set -Eeu.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is impossible to answer, without seeing the code of `soap.sh`. Is it possible for you to break down the script into parts, remove what's proprietary, and post that? Or at least perahps divide and conquer - keep removing bits until the line number reports correctly - whichever bit you removed last would be the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Interestingly, I was debugging a similar script that produced the same result using my traceback library.  What I have noticed is that if the script exits non-zero using 'exit', then the line number is set to 128.  If the script exits as the result of the errexit setting, then the line number is correct.  I haven't yet confirmed this, but it is an observation I have made.